# Extracting phonemes using pocketsphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, phoneme

Is it possible to extract phonemes of the spoken word with the help of pocketsphinx ?

Answer (score 0):

no, this feature is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

From the original question, it sounds like you are looking for a grapheme-to-phoneme solution (G2P).

While pocketsphinx doesn't include one, sphinxtrain does.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxtrain/

Another good option:
http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php